# Page changes when i submit the form

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

```
<form action="/devilmaycry/register?action=addtocart" method="post">            
           <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%=user%>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<%=pid%>"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" onclick="add();"/>
         </form>
```

i am using the above code to submit a form and add a product to cart 
the java code it calls is as follows:

```
 else if(n.equals("addtocart"))
  {
      String user = req.getParameter("user");
      int pid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("pid"));

      k=o.addintocart(user,pid);

     if(k==1)
      {
          pw.println("<h3>Added to cart !!!<h3>");
      }
      else
      {
          pw.println("<h3>Errror , try again <h3><br>");
      }
```

it does add the product to the table but it changes the jsp page ... i tried to use `requestDispatcher` but the URL has many parameters so i want something else through which i can retain the same page and update the table also

Comment: Can you show us the code of the `add()` javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stay on the same page you need to use AJAX rather than submit the form in the traditional way. HTTP works in a request-response fashion, so when the user submits the form, the browser expects to receive a new page in the response from the server, and will thus refresh the page and render the new HTML it receives.

You have two options here:

1. Stick with the traditional HTTP form submission request-response approach, and when you receive the request on the server to add an item to the card, after you add the item to the card, rebuild the URL of the page that is showing the information to the user. In this case it is important to use the 'Redirect-After-Post' approach (i.e. in the response to the form POST you put a redirect to the page). Otherwise if the user refreshes the page by pressing F5, the form data will be resubmitted again and the item added again to the cart.
2. Go for an AJAX approach. In the `add()` function, you need to submit the form using Javascript.  If you are using JQuery it makes it very easy for you to do this. There are various questions / examples if you search around, such as the one [here](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/).

In the latter case you will need to change a bit how you process the information from your Servlet but its the only way to get the browser to stay on the same page (without reloading it). You also have the `success` and `error` handlers, which you can use to show a message on the screen to display the result.

Comment: no problem... which approach did you go for? AJAX with JQuery?

Comment: Ajax with jquery ...but still some issues ...can't get the error message from servlet